# cakephp login form validation on blank username and password

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have checked cakephp validation for a long time to validate my login form. My problem is when i enter username and password as blank the validation not showing.

Login function in UserController.php contains

```
 if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->user->set($this->request->data);
            $errors = $this->user->invalidFields(); 

            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash($this->Auth->authError, 'default', array(), 'auth');
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->loginAction);
            }
        } else {

            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }
        }
```

My User.php Model contains validator as

```
 public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'isUnique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'The username has already been taken.',
            ),

            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
            ),
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'email' => array(
                'rule' => 'email',
                'message' => 'Please provide a valid email address.',
            ),
            'isUnique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
                'message' => 'Email address already in use.',
            ),
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'rule' => array('minLength', 6),
            'message' => 'Passwords must be at least 6 characters long.',
        ),
        'current_password' => array(
            'rule' => '_identical',
            ),
        'name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
        ),
    );
```

Actually my login form contains only usgername and password. But i have set this validation for userregistration form. The validation worked correctly in registration form but in the case of login the validation not working. Yes io know there is lot of questions posted on this website itself regarding the same issue, but nothing solve my problem, i have tried all the stackoverflow questions. Please Help

Comment: There is no point validating user details, either they can log in or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation only occurs when saving, or when you directly call the validation method using:

```
$this->Model->validates();
```

You aren't getting validation errors because you aren't actually validating your data. To get validation errors showing you'll need to do the following:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->set($this->request->data);
        if ($this->User->validates()) {
             echo "This is valid!";
        } else {
             echo "This is invalid";
             $errors = $this->User->validationErrors;
        }
}
```

Comment: calling "$errors = $this->User->invalidFields();" after calling validates is wrong. you need to use $this->User->validationErrors instead!

Comment: Good catch Mark, you are correct as that would duplicate the validation errors. Thanks.